# Oozie: Sub-Workflow Action: how to retrieve sub-workflows id?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am having a Oozie workflow, which calls another workflow to invoke some required actions using `<sub-workflow />` action node. The sub-workflow creates datasets in a directory named after its workflow-id. I need to process datasets located in that directory in the main workflow (the workflow which calls another workflow). For that, its necessary for me to retrieve sub-workflow's id.

Is there any way to get sub-workflow's id from the calling workflow ??

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the Expression Language function wf:actionExternalId

e.g.

```
<kill name="fail">
    <message>problem with: ${wf:actionExternalId("sub-workflow-nodename")}</message>
</kill>
```

You can also try actionTrackerUri or actionExternalStatus

More details on available EF functions here:
http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2_Expression_Language_Functions